# Capacitor Deeplink Not working for some Apps but working for others

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deep-linking, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Working on Ionic Capacitor project and Implemented Deeplinks. But facing weird issue. Deeplinks are working for Some Applications (gmail, whatsapp, etc). But not working for Facebook, Youtube hangouts etc.

app.component.ts

```
setupDeepLink() {
   App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (event: URLOpenListenerEvent) => {
     this.zone.run(() => {
       const slug = event.url.split("/tabs").pop();
       if (slug) {
         this.general.goToPage('/tabs' + slug);
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

AndroiManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
     <data android:host="mydomain.live" android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme="https" />
     <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
     <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
     <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
     <data android:host=" " android:pathPrefix="/" android:scheme=" " />
</intent-filter>
```

Github [Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor-plugins/issues/567#issue-980177224) says its misconfiguration but if its a misconfiguration it should not work with any app.